# How to prevent a user from opening/changing/editing a file inside a jar

Tags: java, java-security

Say I have a file `test.txt` which is bundled inside my jar file. This text file might initially be empty but it will have data written to it as the program runs. I want to prevent the user from expanding my `jar` file and editing this text file in anyway.

Is this possible?

Apologies for the short/seemingly lazy question but I do not have any attempt to show at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply not possible, the jar file is a standard zip file and trivially unpacked.

If you have sensitive information you don't want the user to tamper with you need to be writing it back to a server you control elsewhere.  Anything on the client's machine should be assumed compromised and public.

By the same token you could encrypt the file inside the jar, but in the absence of a separate server the jar would necessarily have to carry the decryption keys with it as well so it becomes a minor inconvenience, but still easily unpicked.

Comment: I understand. I was thinking, if I use obfuscation software like ProGuard to obfuscate the jar file, will it affect any reads/writes to files inside the jar? I know this doesn't prevent the user from opening/editing the file so just focusing on hiding the information inside the file at the moment (without the use of encryption)